# Deiffenbachia (Dumb Cane) houseplant

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, soil-amendment, potting-soil

I have watered it according to the instructions, my indoor temp is around 70-75 F° I moved it closer to this backdoor about a week ago and haven’t given it any nutrients after transplant.

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Comment: What's your question?